# Can't see multiple markers on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-markers

In PostExecute i have this array name : locations

I print Log for more details like that:

```
[lat/lng: (18.5159983333333,-72.2916166666667), lat/lng: (18.5363383333333,-72.3231866666667), lat/lng: (18.5076266666667,-72.3164933333333), lat/lng: (18.54138,-72.2920766666667)]
```

And i try to show all coordinates like that

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++)
            {

            Double latitude = Double.valueOf(locations.get(i).latitude);
            Double longitude = Double.valueOf(locations.get(i).longitude);

            LatLng lng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(lng)
            .title("Test")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources().getIdentifier("Title", "drawable", getPackageName()))));
            } 

        }
```

Google map shows blank. How may i resolve it please??

Comment: where are you putting your loop to add the markers?

Comment: onPostExecute in my AsyncTask

Comment: I mean, where are you calling your loop. Within your onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)?

Comment: onPostExecute in my AsyncTask. The AsyncTask is calling on onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: I just added some kick-start code for you let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add markers when your map is ready to receive them and   that is true when

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
```

is called.

I will try to get you started with this:

You need to setup some variables:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private boolean isMapReady = false;
private ArrayList<LatLng> myLocations = null;
```

the `ArrayList` will contain your locations you get from your `AsyncTask`

Then you need to get the `mapOnReady` setup in your `onCreate()` Methode:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    // What ever else you need

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapViewRidesFoundMap);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Now you need to override the `onMapReady` method:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Set a boolean flag to let other parts of you code  
    // know that the map is ready
    isMapReady = true;


    // If you need to get info from your marker Implement this
    //mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    //    @Override
    //    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    //        showMarkerInfo(marker);
    //        return false;
    //    }
    //});


    //If you need a click listener add this 
    // Add implement the method 'onMapClickLocation'
    //mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    //    @Override
    //    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    //        onMapClickLocation(latLng);
    //    }
    //});

    // call a function to update your locations
    updateMapLocations();
}
```

Within your(!) `protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)`  add code to fill the `myLocations` `ArrayList`

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        myLocations = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++)
        {

            Double latitude = Double.valueOf(locations.get(i).latitude);
            Double longitude = Double.valueOf(locations.get(i).longitude);

            LatLng lng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
            myLocations.put(lng);           
        } 

        // calls the update method when data is available
        this.updateMapLocations();
    }
```

and add a call to `updateMapLocations()` which could look like this:

```
private void updateMapLocations(){
    // update locations won't continue unless the map is ready
    if(!isMapReady) return;

    // Zoom into your location !! if you need too
    // with a destinationLocation of your choice
    // perhaps your first location in you ArrayList
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(destinationLocation, zoomFactor));


    // PseudoCode!!
    // Add your for Loop
    // !!! Check to see if your myLocations ArrayList is null  before you continue !!! 
    // !!! or just add another boolean to you onPostExcecute method
    // And add the Markers

    //Loop Start
    //float hue = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA;
    //MarkerOptions markerOptions = setMarker(latLng, hue)

    // !!! You need to add your destination loop !!!
    //mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    //Loop end!

}


    private MarkerOptions setMarker(LatLng latLng, float hue){
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = null;
    try {
        float markerAlpha = 0.7f;

        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hue));
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.alpha(markerAlpha);
        markerOptions.flat(false);
        markerOptions.title("What Ever");
        markerOptions.snippet("MySnippet");
        markerOptions.draggable(false);
        markerOptions.zIndex(0.0f);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "  setMarker --- " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return markerOptions;
}
```

Notice that `updateMapLocations()` is called in both your `onPostExecute()` and the `onMapReady()` methods. The `onPostExecute()` might be finished before the `onMapReady()` is called. So that first when the map is ready the `updateMapLocations()` will run to completion when data and map are ready.

I wrote this in a text editor - so there will probably be a couple of syntax errors.